# How to calculate circumference of a belly that 3d scanned?

Tags: c#, image-processing, 3d, kinect

I scan a person with kinect v2 and save his/her body in .ply, .obj, .stl formats. I want to calculate the circumference of the belly, biceps etc. from this 3d scanned body.

I am opened to all ideas.

Here is the code I use while saving .obj file.

```
public static void SaveAsciiObjMesh(Mesh mesh, TextWriter writer, bool flipAxes)
    {
        if (null == mesh || null == writer)
        {
            return;
        }

        var vertices = mesh.GetVertices();
        var normals = mesh.GetNormals();
        var indices = mesh.GetTriangleIndexes();

        // Check mesh arguments
        if (0 == vertices.Count || 0 != vertices.Count % 3 || vertices.Count != indices.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(Properties.Resources.InvalidMeshArgument);
        }

        // Write the header lines
        writer.WriteLine("#");
        writer.WriteLine("# OBJ file created by Microsoft Kinect Fusion");
        writer.WriteLine("#");

        // Sequentially write the 3 vertices of the triangle, for each triangle
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
        {
            var vertex = vertices[i];

            string vertexString = "v " + vertex.X.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " ";

            if (flipAxes)
            {
                vertexString += (-vertex.Y).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + (-vertex.Z).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                vertexString += vertex.Y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + vertex.Z.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            writer.WriteLine(vertexString);
        }

        // Sequentially write the 3 normals of the triangle, for each triangle
        for (int i = 0; i < normals.Count; i++)
        {
            var normal = normals[i];

            string normalString = "vn " + normal.X.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " ";

            if (flipAxes)
            {
                normalString += (-normal.Y).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + (-normal.Z).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                normalString += normal.Y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + normal.Z.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            writer.WriteLine(normalString);
        }

        // Sequentially write the 3 vertex indices of the triangle face, for each triangle
        // Note this is typically 1-indexed in an OBJ file when using absolute referencing!
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count / 3; i++)
        {
            string baseIndex0 = ((i * 3) + 1).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string baseIndex1 = ((i * 3) + 2).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string baseIndex2 = ((i * 3) + 3).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            string faceString = "f " + baseIndex0 + "//" + baseIndex0 + " " + baseIndex1 + "//" + baseIndex1 + " " + baseIndex2 + "//" + baseIndex2;
            writer.WriteLine(faceString);
        }
    }
```

I am really unexperienced about image processing and thats a part of my semester homework. I was ill, couldn't go to school that day and they left me the hardest homework. At least hardest for me. So I need some ideas about it. Any info would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Just import it to Autodesk 3D Max and it has in-build volume, surface area, dimension measurement functions. Or if you want to write your own program you can use get the coordinates of surface triangulation. Never used kinect so cannot tell you more unless you can tell us what kind of data you can get from the model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found a video like that. https://youtu.be/jOvaZGloNRo?t=67

This seems like what i am looking for. So please give me an idea about how to implement something like that.